# Always launch certain applications using dedicated graphics card?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

I have Nvidia proprietary drivers installed.

In the (Ubuntu) dock or app-grid, I can right-click on an application, and select "Launch using dedicated Graphics Card".

How can I make certain applications always lunch using the dedicated graphics card by default, when I *left-click* on them in the dock or the app-grid?

Comment: I did it somehow by editing `.desktop` files but lost all data. Are you still looking for solution?

Comment: Yes. If you ever get a chance to recreate this, please post an answer.

Comment: Try appending `X-KDE-RunOnDiscreteGpu=true` to the `.desktop` file. Please reply with any results.